# Java Switch Case Error

Tags: java

I'm here trying to do a switch case to send data to a JTable but althoug it runs the case x, it doesn't send anything to the table.
I will put the code here and I would apreciate if you guys could help me.

Function switch case

```
    private void gerar(int x) {

        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
        model.setRowCount(0);
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        switch (x) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Case 1");
                jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
                        new Object[][]{},
                        new String[]{
                            "Utilizador", "Password"
                        }
                ) {
                    boolean[] canEdit = new boolean[]{
                        false, false
                    };

                    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                        return canEdit[columnIndex];
                    }
                });
                model.setRowCount(0);
                try {
                    System.out.println("Try 1");
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
                    stmt = conn.createStatement();
                    String sql = "SELECT * FROM login";
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        String idd = rs.getString("UTILIZADOR");
                        String pass = rs.getString("PASSWORD");
                        model.addRow(new Object[]{idd, pass});
                    }
                    System.out.println("While 1");
                    rs.close();
                    stmt.close();
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException se) {
                    se.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (stmt != null) {
                        try {
                            stmt.close();
                        } catch (SQLException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    if (conn != null) {
                        try {
                            conn.close();
                        } catch (SQLException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            case 4:
                break;
            case 5:
                break;
            case 6:
                System.out.println("Case 6");
                jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
                        new Object[][]{},
                        new String[]{
                            "Sigla", "Nome", "Faltas JustC", "Faltas InjustC", "Faltas JustS", "Faltas injustS", "DataIni", "DataFim", "Email"
                        }
                ) {
                    boolean[] canEdit = new boolean[]{
                        false, false
                    };

                    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                        return canEdit[columnIndex];
                    }
                });
                model.setRowCount(0);
                try {
                    System.out.println("Try 6");
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
                    stmt = conn.createStatement();
                    String sql = "SELECT * FROM cursos";
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        String idd = rs.getString("Sigla");
                        String pass = rs.getString("Nome");
                        int fjc = rs.getInt("FALTASJUSTIFICADASC");
                        int fijc = rs.getInt("FALTASINJUSTIFICADASC");
                        int fjs = rs.getInt("FALTASJUSTIFICADASS");
                        int fijs = rs.getInt("FALTASINJUSTIFICADASS");
                        int di = rs.getInt("DATA_INICIO");
                        int df = rs.getInt("DATA_FIM");
                        String em = rs.getString("EMAIL");
                        model.addRow(new Object[]{idd, pass, fjc, fijc, fjs, fijs, di, df, em});
                    }
                    System.out.println("While 6");
                    rs.close();
                    stmt.close();
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException se) {
                    se.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (stmt != null) {
                        try {
                            stmt.close();
                        } catch (SQLException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    if (conn != null) {
                        try {
                            conn.close();
                        } catch (SQLException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 7:
                break;
            case 8:
                break;
            case 9:
                break;
            case 10:
                break;
            case 11:
                break;
            case 12:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

What calls it

```
private void jButton10ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    sv();
    gerar(1);
    id1.setEditable(false);
    n1.setText("Utilizador:");
    n2.setText("Password:");
    n3.setVisible(false);
    n4.setVisible(false);
    n5.setVisible(false);
    n6.setVisible(false);
    n7.setVisible(false);
    n8.setVisible(false);
    n9.setVisible(false);
    nn3.setVisible(false);
    nn4.setVisible(false);
    nn5.setVisible(false);
    nn6.setVisible(false);
    nn7.setVisible(false);
    nn8.setVisible(false);
    nn9.setVisible(false);        
  }
```

Comment: Which case does your program run into? Did you step through your program with a debugger?

Comment: I runned debug and it does everything and still doesn't write on the table... i'm not sure why

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't send anything to the table because

```
jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
                new Object[][]{},
                new String[]{
                    "Utilizador", "Password"
                }
        ) {
            boolean[] canEdit = new boolean[]{
                false, false
            };

            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return canEdit[columnIndex];
            }
        });
```

does create a new TableModel for the table.
So when you later go ahead and add rows to your existing Model named 'model', nobody cares because it's not the model for the table anymore anyway.

Comment: I'm sorry, i didn't understand what you said

Comment: @HugoHenriques You are updating one model but the Table is showing another.

Comment: Yes i corrected it already, thanks anyways :)